# Using RewriteCond to change my links

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am a newbie here. I am trying to clean up my links. I made an attempt looking at some of the answers here. I am sure I am not even close....!Can you please help me with this?

Currently my link structure is this...

`xyz.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Touched-By-Light`

But I would like the viewer to see this link `xyz.com/viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Touched-By-Light` ( This means redirect?)

Then rewrite back to my link. ( ?? This is how I understand it)...

So I wrote...

check if the actual request if for "this1"

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /viewgallery.php\?cname=(.*)&pcaption=(.+)

# redirect to "this2"
RewriteRule ^viewgallery\.php /%1/%2/?%3 [R=301,L]

# now rewrite "this2" back to "this1"
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.+)$ /viewgallery.php?cname=$1&pcaption=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Is this correct? I am sure it looks like gibberish ..sorry about that!...

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# externally redirect /viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Touched-By-Light to 
# /viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Touched-By-Light to 
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(viewgallery)\.php\?cname=([^&]+)&pcaption=([^&\s]+) [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301,NE]

# internally forward /viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Touched-By-Light to 
# /viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Touched-By-Light
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?cname=$2&pcaption=$3 [L,QSA]
```

**Explanation:**

1. Rule 1 is for external redirect to make your URL pretty
2. It captures "viewgallery" and parameter cname and pcaption's values in %1, %2, %3
3. Thereafter these captured variables are used to create pretty URL `/viewgallery/%2/%3`
4. Rule 2 is for internal forward
5. From URL: `/viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Touched-By-Light` it captures 3 variables: "viewgallery", "Colorado-Fall" and "Touched-By-Light" into $1, $2, $3
6. Captured variables are used to construct real URL: `/viewgallery.php?cname=$2&pcaption=$3`

**UPDATE:**

```
# /viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Poked to /photos/Colorado-Fall/Poked.jpg
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+viewgallery\.php\?cname=([^&])+&pcaption=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /photos/%1/%2.jpg? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.jpg$ /viewgallery.php?cname=$1&pcaption=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Anubhava...thank you for your answer. I have your answer copied and pasted to my .htaccess file but it did not change anything. Should I be changing/adding anything to your answer?

Comment: No I have tested it also. Copy/paste your latest .htaccess in your question. What URI did you use to test? And where in your directory structure you've placed this .htaccess file.

Comment: Anubhava...my root folder on my server is /home/rajeev/htaccess and in that file I pasted your code. Here is a working link with that code being in my .htaccess file. [http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Journies&pcaption=Shadows-And-Mysteries](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Journies&pcaption=Shadows-And-Mysteries) When you are on the page click on the image and it will navigate to the next image. Strangely, the code takes away the previous/next button. Thanks again..

Comment: Ah you have `pcaption` and I used `caption` in my first rule :P

Comment: Made an edit, pls check it now. Also about your prev, next button make sure to use absolute paths for image, css, js files etc since relative paths won't work after using pretty URLs.

Comment: Anubhava... I am getting an error now.. [http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Touched-By-Light%20HTTP/1.1](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Touched-By-Light%20HTTP/1.1)  not sure what I am doing wrong there...

Comment: SOrry, I had another typo, just fixed it. Pls try it now.

Comment: Anubhava..I tried that but... now the large image itself disappears.Can you check that again for me please? It is on the server now.

Comment: Now your page is trying to load image from: `http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery/Colorado-Journies/photos/404.jpg` which I believe is not correct path.

Comment: Correct path of your image is: `http://www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/404.jpg` and as you can see my previous comment I asked you to `make sure to use absolute paths for image, css, js files etc since relative paths won't work after using pretty URLs.`

Comment: Sorry didn't see that one...so deleted my comment.. okay I guess I need to work on making sure that it is the absolute path... thank you for your help and patience!.

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain the Rewrite that you did word by word... so that I can understand what is going on there...? Because right now its way above my head...

Comment: Sure, I will add some explanation to the answer in few minutes.

Comment: Anubhava ... I need to update my ReWrite statements again since I need to use the absolute paths to my images... so I would like to show http://www.xyz.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Poked to this www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/Poked.jpg how do I rewrite to that? Can you help me...?

Comment: In your original URL: `www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/Poked.jpg` there is no `Colorado-Fall` but in your target URL there is. May be you can use `www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/Colorado-Fall/Poked.jpg`

Comment: Anubhava thank you... my actual path to the images is www.rajeevthomas.com/photos/xyz.jpg so first I thought I need to ReWrite the links to this format xyz.com/viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Touched-By-Light but since gallery script uploads everything to 'photos' folder in my root directory I think I need to use ReWrite statements to # externally redirect /viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Touched-By-Light to 
# /photos/poked.jpg. I hope this makes sense...

Comment: Yes if you want to externally redirect `/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Poked` to `/photos/Poked.jpg` with 301 that is indeed possible. Let me know it that's right and I can suggest you rewrite for this.

Comment: Thank you Anubhava, that's what I need to do.

Comment: Ok check the rule in UPDATE section.

Comment: Thank you Anubhava...it works and when thumbnail on this page is clicked it takes to the actual image. [link](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall) but I loose my ability to go to the next image.  The last part of the code from before, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?cname=$2&pcaption=$3 [L,QSA]` is it still supposed to construct real URL?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand which part isn't working on your linked page.

Comment: Anubhava I removed the ReWrite rules so you can see how the gallery works without it. When you click on the each thumbnail it takes you to the larger image and from there you can click the next button to continue/navigate to the next image..  [Please check this link](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall) But with the rules in htacces the ability to navigate goes away...

Comment: I checked that. Reason is today's rule of `/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Poked to /photos/Poked.jpg` make it just goto `/photos/Poked.jpg` and loads the image but rest of the page content which is coming from `/viewgallery.php` won't come. And we can internally forward `/photos/Poked.jpg to /viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Poked` since we have lost cname in external rewrite earlier.

Comment: Anubhava...it sounds like that's what is happening here. How can we do that by the code above?

Comment: As I suggested earlier keep `cname` also in pretty URL. So instead of `/photos/Poked.jpg` use `/photos/Colorado-Fall/Poked.jpg` with an additional internal rewrite rule (that I can provide if you agree).

Comment: Anubhava... I have no problem keeping the cname but that's not a real folder's name ( Colorado Fall) in my root directory. cname just comes from the category name from database. Either /photos/Poked.jpg OR /photos/Colorado-Fall/Poked.jpg will be fine. Yes I agree...can you help me with internally forwarding /photos/Poked.jpg to /viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Poked  Thank you Anubhava!.

Comment: Clarifying once again your pretty URL will be: `/photos/Colorado-Fall/Poked.jpg`

Comment: It is on my gallery now..but it is taking the link to this final link rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery/Colorado-Fall/Early-Colors... here is the link to my gallery [My Gallery](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall) And if it helps..it is showing up as a 404 error.

Comment: Made some edits. Commented out earlier rule that conflicting. And added a `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f`

Comment: I added the whole ReWrite rule to a text file and uploaded to my site. Here is the link..[link to htaccess text](http://rajeevthomas.com/Anubhava.txt) can you check this please. To see if I am doing it right..link I don't know if I am doing anything wrong from my side... but the final link shows up as rajeevthomas.com/photos/l/Colorful-Window.jpg

Comment: Difficult to understand what's going on with so many comments. If you can trust me in giving a temporary access to you server then I can login and see file/directory structure before giving a concrete solution.

Comment: Sure Anubhava... how do I send it to you? I am sure I cannot share it here?

Comment: All the info are sent to you at your email id... thank you for helping Anubhava...